# Populating Reliable Dictionary on InvokeLossAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I'm using Azure Service Bus, together with topics, in a DDD mindset.

Every entity change is backed with an event picked up by any subscriber interested. One of those is a stateful service that could pick up these events to populate a reliable collection (Dictionary).
However, I'm not a fan of the backup process from disk, especially not during development. It would make our life much easier if we could hook in a call to the entity store (Cosmos DB) to build the collection from scratch, during development but also during new application pushes (if we want). This would also save us from keeping upgrade patterns in mind when the entity structure changed, as we could trigger a Restore via the API when required

Is this possible in the InvokeLossAsync method, or are there better approaches?

Comment: If you're storing state outside of the cluster, why do you also use a stateful service?

Comment: I think what you need is a CACHE instead of a Stateful Service. Like LoekD said, if the state is managed elsewhere, you shouldn't bother to use stateful services. A caching system like Redis would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. I was planning to use Redis, but everywhere in MS documentation, they put their reliable dictionaries in comparisons with Redis, so I naturally assumed it's one of both. And since Reliable dictionaries are in-app, the latency is much smaller hence I thought of reliable dictionaries as a good approach for the caching/hot data (as I won't indeed do anything else than cache the data...)